# Streaming content from Surface 2 to Xbox 360

Tags: windows-8.1, streaming, xbox360, xbox-music

I recently watched this [YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wG1b0yBJHLM) where I learnt some cool things about what my tablet is capable of. However, when I went home to try them, the result was somewhat anticlimactic.

Firstly attempting to stream Xbox Music to the Xbox, it took an *age* to connect, I actually stopped it the first time, connected with Smartglass (to make sure it was working, and it did - connected within 15 seconds) and then tried it again, still took 1 minute plus. Also, as soon as I went back to the start screen to do some other things the music started spluttering and then stopped altogether. Any ideas what might be the cause?

I've also read this [Microsoft article](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/use-play-to) which explains that Photos can be shared using the native app, however when I follow the same steps to stream it says Photos cannot play anything at the moment. I tried in slideshow mode, same result.

Comment: Are we talking about Windows 8.1 or Windows 8.0, and what version what the video using, because on the surface they would look nearly identical.

Comment: Me personally, using 8.1 on a Surface 2. He does suggest in the description that he was also using 8.1 on a Surface 2 so it should be an identical setup.

Comment: Can you clarify if you're using Xbox 360, or Xbox One?

Comment: Xbox 360, sorry I only mentioned that in the tags